# Why is this the requirement for invertibility within the context of canonical transformations in mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm reading "Analytical Mechanics", by Hand and Finch. In page 210, there's the following statement, regarding the generating function $F$ for some lagrangian such that $L'=\lambda L-\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}t}$:

> "There are some restrictions on what you can use for $F(q,Q,t)$. A necessary and sufficient condition for an acceptable $F$ is that $\frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{q}\partial{Q}} \neq 0$. If the mixed second derivative vanishes, it can be shown that the transformation will not be invertible."

I can't really find a proof for this within the book, and I don't understand it intuitively. I vaguely remember a similar condition and similar statements in math classes I've previously taken, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In a [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation)
$$ (q,p,t)\longrightarrow (Q,P,t)$$
of [type 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_1_generating_function), we must demand that the transformation
$$ (q,Q,t)\longrightarrow (q,p,t)$$
is invertible, i.e. that the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)
$$ \frac{\partial(q,p,t)}{\partial(q,Q,t)}~=~ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\cr \frac{\partial^2F_1}{\partial q^2} &\frac{\partial^2F_1}{\partial q\partial Q}&\frac{\partial^2F_1}{\partial q\partial t}\cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
is invertible. Here we used the type-1 relation
$$ p~=~\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial q} .$$

Comment: Oh, alright, that makes more sense. So it's an application of the inverse function theorem, then? What would the transformation look like as a matrix, though?